# Codeigniter Single Image into Multiple Resize

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter. This is what I want to do:

1. User uploads a profile picture.
2. I resize the original image to several sizes, e.g. 400×300, 200×200, and 32×32.

But what I when I upload the image is that it's re-sized successfully *only for one* dimension, 400×300.

Here is my code:

```
 $config['image_library']   = 'gd2';
 $config['source_image']    = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
 $config['create_thumb']    = TRUE;
 $config['maintain_ratio']  = TRUE;
 $config['width']           = 400;
 $config['height']          = 300;
 $config['new_image']   = 400x300image;
 $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
 $this->image_lib->resize();
 $this->image_lib->clear()

 $config['image_library']   = 'gd2';
 $config['source_image']    = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
 $config['create_thumb']    = TRUE;
 $config['maintain_ratio']  = TRUE;
 $config['width']           = 200;
 $config['height']          = 200;
 $config['new_image']   = 200x200image;
 $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
 $this->image_lib->resize();
 $this->image_lib->clear()

 $config['image_library']   = 'gd2';
 $config['source_image']    = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
 $config['create_thumb']    = TRUE;
 $config['maintain_ratio']  = TRUE;
 $config['width']           = 32;
 $config['height']          = 32;
 $config['new_image']   = 32x32image;
 $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
 $this->image_lib->resize();
 $this->image_lib->clear();
```

I tried using different config names like `$config2` and `$config3` but I did't get the output.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: are you sure your `$config['new_image']` isn't a string? you are simply saying `= 200x200image;`. Is `200x200image` a predefined constant?

Comment: @goldenparrot $config['new_image'] is the saved filename.  It should be a string, which, along with a few other syntax errors in his code should throw errors. Good eye.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a similar function built into one of my CI apps.  In my case, I needed the config files in another function, so I built separate versions.

Don't load the library multiple times.  Once is fine. Just reinitialize the the library with your new config each time.

```
 $this->load->library('image_lib');

 /* First size */
 $configSize1['image_library']   = 'gd2';
 $configSize1['source_image']    = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
 $configSize1['create_thumb']    = TRUE;
 $configSize1['maintain_ratio']  = TRUE;
 $configSize1['width']           = 400;
 $configSize1['height']          = 300;
 $configSize1['new_image']   = '400x300image';

 $this->image_lib->initialize($configSize1);
 $this->image_lib->resize();
 $this->image_lib->clear();

 /* Second size */    
 $configSize2['image_library']   = 'gd2';
 $configSize2['source_image']    = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
 $configSize2['create_thumb']    = TRUE;
 $configSize2['maintain_ratio']  = TRUE;
 $configSize2['width']           = 200;
 $configSize2['height']          = 200;
 $configSize2['new_image']   = '200x200image';

 $this->image_lib->initialize($configSize2);
 $this->image_lib->resize();
 $this->image_lib->clear();
```

And so on.  I suppose, for memory's sake, you could unset and reset the config file, as was suggested above, but if you plan on using the image resizing in separate controller methods as I did, I found it helpful to save those separately.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did't implemented your concept yet, but i trust this will work.

Comment: No problem. as @goldenparrot mentioned, you should check your code for syntax errors, there are a few in there.

Comment: @SoundharRaj If it helps please acceot the answer

Comment: i don't know why, it work some where for me and don't work somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, CI stores all the libraries after loading them into a static array, and will not load a library again once it is loaded.

So, what you can do is, you can initialize it again with new config:

```
$this->image_lib->clear();

// make changes to the $conig here

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
```

That should work.

[Source.](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewreply/781093/)

Comment: +1 This is the solution. I would recommend using different names for $config var or reinitializing the variable for each new resize.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use image_moo library for this....its dead simple,lean and clean. See this: http://www.matmoo.com/digital-dribble/codeigniter/image_moo/